# Вывод определенного ID из MySQL в PHP в формате JSON и настройка .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, api

В общем, есть код:

```html
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'login', 'pass') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('table') or die('Не могу выбрать базу данных');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ma_players WHERE SID=''";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $rows[] = array($row);
    }

    echo json_encode($rows)
?>
```

У меня два вопроса:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы выводило определенного пользователя в формате `JSON` из нескольких таблиц, к примеру `ma_players`, `ma_question`, `ma_answers` и `ma_violations`?
2. Скрипт будет лежать, к примеру, на этом сайте: 
   `site.ru/script.php?SID=1`
   Нужно, чтобы он открывался по адресу:
   `site.ru/api/1`

Answer (score 0):

1. "Как сделать так ..."- сделать более сложный запрос с join'ами по нескольким таблицам. Или сделать несколько запросов по разным таблицам и самому сформировать итоговые данные.
2. "Скрипт будет лежать ..." если у вас apache, то смотреть в сторону mod_rewrite и его rewrite rules. Под nginx тоже есть похожая функциональность.

Comment: Так я  и спрашивал как сделать несколько запросов к SID=1 чтобы мог выводиться потом по site.ru/script?SID=1